# Where is Prestashop $product['name'] assigned with its value during checkout?

Tags: prestashop, combinations, prestashop-1.7

Having combinations in Prestashop, the product name is correctly displayed in the order conformation. However during checkout, only the base product name, and not the combination product name is displayed. See: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/14361

For the order confirmation I think that $product['name'] is defined in `/classes/order/OrderDetail.php` as:

```
 $product['name'] .
            ((isset($product['attributes']) && $product['attributes'] != null) ?
                ' - ' . $product['attributes'] : '');
```

But where is `$product['name']` defined during the checkout phase (before an order exists), that is meant as in `themes/classic/templates/checkout/_partials/cart-summary-product-line.tpl`?

Answer (score 1):

`$product['name']` is defined in class `cart`. In function `getProducts()`

Regards

Comment: That `function getProducts()` in class cart is located at [/classes/Cart.php around line 617](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/aec97ddb1551fd7d6d56f75549a992d6937caf50/classes/Cart.php#L617) in the current development branch, though can't find where '`name`' gets its value.

Comment: close question if ok :)

Comment: I still haven't found where that `$product['name']` is filled with its string value of/for an actual product.

Comment: The product name is retrieved in the getProducts () query of the class Cart.

Comment: My PHP reading skills are novice. Do you mean `$this->_products = array();` around [line 747](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/aec97ddb1551fd7d6d56f75549a992d6937caf50/classes/Cart.php#L747)?